# Azure functions v4 net 6 on Linux

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have developed an Azure Function `v4` with `.net 6.0.` It contains one triggered function.
[image]

Locally everything works fine. After deploying it to Azure it works fine for all plans with `Windows OS` but it doesn't work for plans: `Premium(EP1)` and `App Service Plan(P1V2)` (except `Consumption`) with `Linux`.

I get the error message: "*Error: Error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0" occurred while parsing the response body - Service Unavailable.*". Here is my not working config. Please note I'm using `Premium(EP1)`
[image]

The same function is working fine on plans `Premium(EP1)` with `Windows OS`, `Consumption` with `Linux`
[image]

My goal is to run Azure function `v4` with `.net 6.0.` on `Linux` on the plan `Premium(EP1)`

Comment: **Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.** please check **[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand your images but when I look at them it looks like you have several instances of same Function App running on same App Service Plan but with different OS, right? If thats the case then you are not able to do such, see the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#create-a-premium-plan):

> You can run more than one function app in the same Premium plan, but they must both run on the same operating system (Windows or Linux).

Comment: I use different Service plans and different storage accounts